# Como fazer consulta SQL usando comparador like e vários valores fora de ordem

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Procurei por respostas aqui na comunidade mas não encontrei nada específico. Eu tenho uma página onde posso pesquisar o nome de clientes previamente cadastrados em um banco de dados MySQL. Atualmente, estou usando as seguintes sentenças:

PHP: `$valor = str_replace(' ', '%', $pesquisa);`

SQL: `"select * from user where nome like '%".$valor."%' order by nome asc;"`

Sendo que variável PHP **$pesquisa**, vem de um formulário de pesquisa na mesma página. 
(O código acima me permite fazer pesquisas com mais de um valor).
Por exemplo, se houver um cliente no banco de dados chamado **Luiz Henrique da Silva**, e eu pesquisar por *Luiz*, *Luiz Henrique*, ou até mesmo *Luiz Silva*, esse código funcionará perfeitamente, listando o tal usuário.

No entanto, se eu pesquisar o nome fora de ordem, como *Silva Henrique*, ou *da Silva Luiz*, o usuário não será listado. Como poderia possibilitar essa pesquisa reversa de uma maneira simples?

Answer (score 1):

> Sintaxe de 'like' em SQL:

```
SELECT (campos) FROM (tabelas) WHERE campo1 LIKE "%variavel%";
```

> No contexto em que a queres usar ficaria mais ou menos parecido com isto:

```
$comando = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE nome LIKE '%$valor%' ORDER BY nome ASC;"
```

> Mas para conseguires encontrar o registo **Luiz Henrique da Silva** procurando por **Luiz Silva**, não iria dar, apenas se tivesses em 2 variaveis diferentes e assim poderias fazer algo como isto na tua query em SQL:

```
SELECT (campos) FROM (tabelas) WHERE campo1 LIKE "%Luiz%" AND campo1 LIKE "%Silva%";
```

> E assim apareceria o registo **Luiz Henrique da Silva**.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: Olá amigo. Obrigado por comentar. Mas como disse na descrição, a função str_replace me ajuda nessa questão, ela substitui o espaço entre as palavras na pesquisa, por um %, assim se eu pesquisar Luiz Silva ele será listado perfeitamente. A minha dúvida é como realizar uma pesquisa reversa. Quero pesquisar Silva Luiz, e ter esse usuário retornado também. Entende?